# Zend 2 After login how to set user

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I have the following code and which works, but now the next step.

How and where do i have to set a session so the script "sees" that the user is already logged in?

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $securePass = $this->getUsersTable()->getUserByUsername( $this->params()->fromPost('username') );       
    if( $securePass ){   
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
        if ($bcrypt->verify( $this->params()->fromPost('password') , $securePass->password)) {

            $sm          = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $dbAdapter   = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter(
                    $dbAdapter,
                    'users',
                    'username',
                    'password'
                    );
            $authAdapter
                ->setIdentity($securePass->username)
                ->setCredential($securePass->password);                           

            $result = $authAdapter->authenticate($authAdapter);
            echo $result->getIdentity() . "\n\n";
        } 
        else {

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoginController.php

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $securePass = $this->getUsersTable()->getUserByUsername( $this->params()->fromPost('username') );       
    if( $securePass ){   
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
        if ($bcrypt->verify( $this->params()->fromPost( 'password' ) , $securePass->password ) ) {

            $sm          = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $dbAdapter   = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter(
                $dbAdapter,
                'users',
                'username',
                'password'
            );
            $authAdapter->setIdentity($securePass->username)
            ->setCredential($securePass->password);                           
            $result = $authAdapter->authenticate($authAdapter);

            $sesssionData = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject();

            $auth = new AuthenticationService();
            $storage = $auth->getStorage();
            $storage->write($sesssionData);

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user_list');
        }
    }
}



public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{

    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $app            = $e->getParam('application');
    $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', array($this, 'setLayoutTitle'));
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'checkLogin'));
}

public function checkLogin(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $iden = new AuthenticationService();
    if( $iden->getIdentity() === NULL ){
        $matches    = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
        $getController = explode( '\\', $controller );  

        if( isset( $getController[2] ) && $getController[2] != 'Login' ){
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            return $controller->plugin('redirect')->toRoute('login');
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Zend way of doing it is to use Authentication component that handles this for you.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html

This will allow you to check if user is logged in (you will have to setup the authentication adapter first):

```
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
// TODO set-up authentication adapter
$auth = new AuthenticationService()
$identity = $auth->getIdentity();
```

For accessing post data you should also leverage the framework instead of accessing $_POST directly. In your controller:

```
$this->params()->fromPost('username');
$this->params()->fromPost('password');
```

This will guide you through the whole process of adding authentication layer to your app:

https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.dbtable.html

Comment: This shows how to get an identity, but does not explain how to set it in the first place.

Comment: I have changed my script and that works. This works fine, why so complicated? Now i can check if the $container->access is 1 or 0

Comment: @Bas If you think this answer is complicated, then I am sorry to say that zf2 is not for you. This answer shows how to use `Zend\Authentication` component to login user. In your way, all the domain logic is added in controller which makes controller too bloated. So, this also violates the MVC structure!

Comment: @Ujjwal Ojha, New format, now how do i check if user isset and where can i do this global, see the new code above

Answer (score 1):

Using the AuthenticationService provided by Zend, setting the user in the PHP session is automatically taken care of.

A good thing to understand the authentication mechanism would be to read, and code along with this introduction to authentication:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html#adapters

In a custom AuthenticationAdapter "setting the user in the session", or identity persistence, would be done by returning \Zend\Authentication\Result with the result of the authentication and the user identity in the authenticate() method.

```
$user = $this->userService->findByEmail($this->email);

if($user !== false) {
    if($this->encryption->verify($this->password, $user->getPassword()) {
        return new Result(Result::SUCCESS, $user);
    }

    return new Result(Result::FAILURE, null);
}

$this->userService being the UserService that leads to the UserMapper
(more about Services: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html)
$user being the User entity with the encrypted password stored
$this->encryption being your encryption method (Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt for example)
$this->email being the email/username provided by the form
$this->password being the password provided by the form
Result being Zend\Authentication\Result
```

This is an easy approach. More detailed Result types are:

```
/**
 * General Failure
 */
const FAILURE                        =  0;
/**
 * Failure due to identity not being found.
 */
const FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND     = -1;
/**
 * Failure due to identity being ambiguous.
 */
const FAILURE_IDENTITY_AMBIGUOUS     = -2;
/**
 * Failure due to invalid credential being supplied.
 */
const FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID     = -3;
/**
 * Failure due to uncategorized reasons.
 */
const FAILURE_UNCATEGORIZED          = -4;
/**
 * Authentication success.
 */
const SUCCESS                        =  1;
```